# R Markdown won't knit: Error comes from plotting graph?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

When I run this code:

```
y = 2 + x^2 + 0.5*x^3
x <- seq(-10, 10, .1)
qplot(x,y,geom="line")
```

it works fine and the graph shows up. The only problem is when I try to knit the rmd to html an error pops up regarding the first line of code:

```
y = 2 + x^2 + 0.5*x^3
```

The error says: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found Calls:  ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval Execution halted

It's referring to the x in the equation because thats the line where the error occurs. I don't know how to make it knit and have not seen other people encounter this specific problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that when you run the code in a terminal, x exists already. Whereas in the RMarkdown document, the line that defines y (and uses x) fails because x is defined after it. So just move the line that defines x to be above the line that defines y.

Comment: @neilfws That fixed it! Thank you so much, I did not realize something so simple could cause such a big headache! Definitely noted for future reference.